# Facebook api does not reload after login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, api

Basically, on my website I've added a login button for facebook, and the login works fine. However, you have to refresh once you've logged in to see that you're logged in. I've looked up the problem and the codes provided did not work.

Here is the code that I'm currently using in attempt to refresh the page after a successful login:

```
FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function(response) {
   window.location.reload();
});
```

Although that should work, it doesn't; it's not even refreshing the page as specified in the code. Here's the code for the Facebook login button:

```
 <fb:login-button perms="email,user_likes,user_photos">CONNECT Bla Bla</fb:login-button>
```

Could anybody please suggest some kind of fix as I've been working on this for many hours and it seems somewhat of an inconvenience for users to reload after a login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code for your FB login button

```
 <fb:login-button scope="email,user_likes,user_photos"    onlogin='window.location="http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.php";'>Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the page now goes to a location, however once it reloads, it's still not logged in, I have to reload from my browser, and then it works. And in the url, it adds 'error=unknown_user' to the end of it? But that's fine once I reload the page manually.

Comment: You can see the complete implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810813/automatic-login-facebook-php-sdk/20812884#20812884  , the only thing needed is adding the login button in the above example

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that's still interested in an answer, for this, use the following code: Thanks to @Abhik Chakraborty for the base of the code.

```
<fb:login-button scope="email,user_likes,user_photos"    onlogin='window.location.reload(true);'>Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

And that will then force your browser to reload the website (like a 'hard' reload).